# Google Translate API double quotes

Tags: java, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google Translate API with Java and whenever I send an English text with double quotes to be translated, I get this weird formatting:

Source text (en):

```
"Fresh Air"
```

Google's response (pt):

```
&quot;Ar Fresco&quot;
```

Google's response (es):

```
&quot;Aire Fresco&quot;
```

Desired result:

`"Ar Fresco"` (for Portuguese) and `"Aire Fresco"` (for Spanish)

Java code used to retrieve translations:

```
String google_key = "SOME_GOOGLE_API_KEY";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
    Translate t = new Translate.Builder(
      com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                    com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
                            .setApplicationName("myApp").build();

    List<String> totranslate = new ArrayList<String>();
    totranslate.add(sourceText);
    Translate.Translations.List list = t.new Translations().list(
            totranslate,
            targetLanguage.getCode());
    list.setKey(google_key);
    TranslationsListResponse response = list.execute();
    for (TranslationsResource tr : response.getTranslations()) {
        result.add(tr.getTranslatedText());
    }
    System.out.println("Google translation: ["+sourceText+"]("+targetLanguage+"): "+result.get(0));
    return result.get(0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to avoid this kind of result and get the double quotes as in the original source text?

Answer (score 2):

google api translation is considering the input by default as HTML, you can change the format to "text" or "text/plain"
https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/translate/Translate.TranslateOption.html#format-java.lang.String-